# Replace Module Text in MS Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

How do I do a search and replace of text within a module in Access from another module in access?  I could not find this on Google.

FYI, I figured out how to delete a module programatically:

Call DoCmd.DeleteObject(acModule, modBase64)

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? I can't conceive of a need for this, except if you're re-inventing the wheel of Access search and replace utilities. Certainly, it's not something that is of any use in a production application, since you just replace the front end. If you haven't split your app into front end/back end, then that's perhaps the reason you think you need to do this.

Comment: This is a great question I needed the answer (tho still trying to get it to work.  This question REALLY DOES NEED a vba tag !

Comment: As for David's comment, Greg supplied a splendid reason (below).  I want to run complex pattern-oriented searches.

Comment: I did get it to work, you can see in my comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found this code:

```
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'Function to Search for a String in a Code Module. It will return True if it is found and
'False if it is not. It has an optional parameter (NewString) that will allow you to
'replace the found text with the NewString. If NewString is not included in the call
'to the function, the function will only find the string not replace it.
'
'Created by Joe Kendall 02/07/2003
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function SearchOrReplace(ByVal ModuleName As String, ByVal StringToFind As String, _
        Optional ByVal NewString, Optional ByVal FindWholeWord = False, _
        Optional ByVal MatchCase = False, Optional ByVal PatternSearch = False) As Boolean

    Dim mdl As Module
    Dim lSLine As Long
    Dim lELine As Long
    Dim lSCol As Long
    Dim lECol As Long
    Dim sLine As String
    Dim lLineLen As Long
    Dim lBefore As Long
    Dim lAfter As Long
    Dim sLeft As String
    Dim sRight As String
    Dim sNewLine As String

    Set mdl = Modules(ModuleName)

    If mdl.Find(StringToFind, lSLine, lSCol, lELine, lECol, FindWholeWord, _
            MatchCase, PatternSearch) = True Then
        If IsMissing(NewString) = False Then
            ' Store text of line containing string.
            sLine = mdl.Lines(lSLine, Abs(lELine - lSLine) + 1)
            ' Determine length of line.
            lLineLen = Len(sLine)
            ' Determine number of characters preceding search text.
            lBefore = lSCol - 1
            ' Determine number of characters following search text.
            lAfter = lLineLen - CInt(lECol - 1)
            ' Store characters to left of search text.
            sLeft = Left$(sLine, lBefore)
            ' Store characters to right of search text.
            sRight = Right$(sLine, lAfter)
            ' Construct string with replacement text.
            sNewLine = sLeft & NewString & sRight
            ' Replace original line.
            mdl.ReplaceLine lSLine, sNewLine
        End If
        SearchOrReplace = True
    Else
        SearchOrReplace = False
    End If

    Set mdl = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.  My experience trying to make it work is that you must have all modules opened in the VBA IDE, or the Modules() command will break with error 7961.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean how to do this programatically (otherwise it's just ctrl-h). Unless this is being done in the context of a VBE Add-In, it is rarely (if ever) a good idea. Self modifying code is often flagged by AV software an although access will *let* you do it, it's not really robust enough to handle it, and can lead to corruption problems etc. In addition, if you go with self modifying code you are preventing yourself from ever being able to use an MDE or even a project password. In other words, you will never be able to protect your code. It might be better if you let us know what problem you are trying to solve with self modifying code and see if a more reliable solution could be found.

Comment: The goal of this is to delete sections of code before the source code is distributed.  Right now I am manually doing a search and delete every time I want to do a source code distribution.  I want to automate it to save time.

Comment: Sweet, I do that kind of thing myself. I just didn't want to help you hurt yourself:)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the VBA object browser for the Access library.  Under the Module object you can search the Module text as well as make replacements.  Here is an simple example:

In Module1

```
Sub MyFirstSub()
    MsgBox "This is a test"
End Sub
```

In Module2

```
Sub ChangeTextSub()
    Dim i As Integer

    With Application.Modules("Module1")
        For i = 1 To .CountOfLines
            If InStr(.Lines(i, 1), "This is a Test") > 0 Then
                .ReplaceLine i, "Msgbox ""It worked!"""
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

After running ChangeTextSub, MyFirstSub should read

```
Sub MyFirstSub()
MsgBox "It worked!"
End Sub
```

It's a pretty simple search but hopefully that can get you going.

Answer (score 0):

additional for the function (looping through all the lines)

```
Public Function ReplaceWithLine(modulename As String, StringToFind As String, NewString As String)
    Dim mdl As Module
    Set mdl = Modules(modulename)

    For x = 0 To mdl.CountOfLines
     Call SearchOrReplace(modulename, StringToFind, NewString)
    Next x

    Set mdl = Nothing
End Function
```

Enjoy ^^