# Application.Goto other subroutine's line error

Tags: ms-access, excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I have in Excel this simple piece of code. If I run sub test, it takes me to the sub example and place the cursor in front of 'Hello. I want to do the same in VBA within a Ms Access 2010 module but I get: "Compile error: Method or data member not found".
How can I make it work in Ms Access?

```
Sub test()
    Application.Goto "example"
End Sub

Sub example()
   'Hello
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this method:

```
Call example
```

pay attention, the sub you wanna call must be accessible form the first.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't want to call and run the sub example. I just want to go to the line of the sub example, not run the code inside. Like going to the line within a sub. It works in Excel but not in Access.

Comment: Sorry my mistake for not explaining it better. The best way to understand it, it's to paste both subs in the VBE in Excel and run sub test. Basically if I assign sub test to a button it will go to the sub example in the VBE (not running that sub, just showing it). I hope it's clearer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using some code by [Mark Lavine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865530/replace-module-text-in-ms-access-using-vba) and [a Microsoft article](http://smallbusiness.support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/187318) I've managed to create the sub below. It prints the module and line of each occurrence of the string in the Immediate Window. I'd like to be able to go to those specific lines programmatically too.

```
Sub FindStringInAllModules()
Dim c As String
c = "example" 'Search for string "test"
Dim i As Integer
Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object
Set dbs = Application.CurrentProject
For Each obj In dbs.AllModules
    If obj.IsLoaded = True Then
        With Application.Modules(obj.Name)
            For i = 1 To .CountOfLines
                If InStr(.Lines(i, 1), c) > 0 Then
                     Debug.Print obj.Name & " line " & i
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    End If
Next obj
End Sub
```